# Export the data into a PDF format with Tomahawk?

Tags: java, jsf, myfaces, tomahawk

In my application I am trying to export the data from the `<h:DataTable>` into a PDF file using Apache TomaHawk. While loading the page I am getting an exception. I have Pasted my code and the exception below.

**JSF Code**

```
<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/sandbox" prefix="s"%>
<f:view>
<html>
    <body>
        <h:form>
            <p>
                This component allows to export the datatable contents to an excel
                or pdf file.
            </p>

            <br>
            <t:dataTable id="tbl_cars" var="car" value="#{exBean.list}"
                preserveDataModel="false">
                <t:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Id" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                </t:column>

                <t:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Type" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.type}" />
                </t:column>

                <t:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Color" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                </t:column>

            </t:dataTable>
            <h:commandButton action="" value="Export as excel">
                <s:exporterActionListener for="tbl_cars" fileType="XLS" />
            </h:commandButton>

            <br>

            <h:commandButton action="" value="Export as pdf">
                <s:exporterActionListener for="tbl_cars" fileType="PDF" />
            </h:commandButton>


        </h:form>

    </body>

</html> 
    </f:view>
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class    org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ExtensionsPhaseListener.writeCodeBeforeBodyEnd(ExtensionsPhaseListener.java:130)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ExtensionsPhaseListener.getCodeBeforeBodyEnd(ExtensionsPhaseListener.java:104)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ExtensionsPhaseListener.getJavaScriptCodeAndStoreInRequest(ExtensionsPhaseListener.java:94)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ExtensionsPhaseListener.afterPhase(ExtensionsPhaseListener.java:70)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersAfter(PhaseListenerManager.java:92)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:142)
at org.apache.myfaces.custom.ppr.PPRLifecycleWrapper.render(PPRLifecycleWrapper.java:84)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:182)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>    org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig
> ```

Either the classpath is dirty (duplicate JAR files of different versions which get collided with each other), or you simply forgot to install [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html) and/or its dependencies [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload), [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging), [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io) and/or [commons-el](http://commons.apache.org/el) (just put JAR file(s) in `/WEB-INF/lib`).

Comment: have checked everything u have told.have followed the steps what u have mentioned only.

Comment: Sorry, but the exception proves otherwise. If you're *only* sure that Tomahawk is installed the right way, then there's undoubtely a version collision. Cleanup your classpath from older versioned duplicates and align all versions. Or reread the stacktrace to find any **root cause** (the part below it), for the case you haven't done/understood it yet.